# Solving $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt {x-1} - 2} = 1-\sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt{x-1}}$ with symmetric polynomials

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

I need to solve the following with symmetric polynomials, but I do not understand what to do here.
$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt {x-1} - 2} = 1-\sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Comment: Your question might be closed unless you show some work toward solving it yourself. You should edit it to show some of your work. HINT: Can you find two equations in $u$ and $v$ if you let $u^3=\sqrt{x-1}-2$ and $v^3=9-\sqrt{x-1}$? Then see if you can replace the original equation with an equation with just one variable, either $u$ or $v$.

Comment: I can`t understand. I got u = 1-v, but I do not understand what to do next.

Comment: What does $u^3+v^3$ equal. That would give you a second equation in $u$ and $v$ making it possible to solve for $u$ and $v$ and then for $x$.

Comment: And you should add what you get to your question so your work can be seen. Questions which show no partial work are frequently closed or downvoted.

Comment: Thank you for hints! I want to try to solve it myself now and then I`ll show my solution.

Comment: Excellent idea!

Comment: Thank you very much! I solve it thanks to your hints!

Comment: Yes, that is the correct solution. Congratulations! But you should keep the original post and just add the graphic to it.

Comment: Recheck the solution to your equation $\sqrt{x-1}=1$.

Comment: There has to be a square root.

Comment: Yes, I corrrected it.

Comment: Everything is OK, I think.